# $_POST key with multiple values for checkbox options

Tags: php, http-post

I am building a $_POST query using `http_build_query`, but I need to transmit multiple values for one key. The problem refers to a HTML form from the [United States Naval Observatory 
Flagstaff Station](http://www.nofs.navy.mil/data/FchPix/cfch.html). In the section `Catalogue Lists` you can select multiple values to be shown.

After submitting a request you will get a overview of the search parameters. A short extract shows that multiple values refer to the same key.

```
...
colbits = cb_id
colbits = cb_ra
...
colbits = cb_mag
...
```

The thing is that I don't see a chance to transmit multiple values for the same key in PHP. If i would do it as following, the value for the key would be overwritten.

```
$url = 'http://www.nofs.navy.mil/cgi-bin/tfch4.test.cgi';
$data = array('colbits' => 'cb_id', 'colbits' => 'cb_ra', 'colbits' => 'cb_mag');

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Is there any workaround for this? I already tried to send the different values as an array for the key „colbits“, but this doesn't worked as expected.

Comment: I think you'll have to create the query string by hand. This API doesn't use the standard method for receiving an array of values.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, @Barmar. I have appended the params for the columns manually after the http_build_query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending the params to the generated query string by `http_build_query` did the trick.

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)."&colbits=cb_id&colbits=cb_altid&colbits=cb_ra&colbits=cb_mag",
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an array in $_POST called 'colbits': 
`$_POST['colbits'] == ['cb_id','cb_ra','cb_mag']`
...the correct way to do it is to put a pair of square brackets after 'colbits' definition, likes this:

`$data = array('colbits[]' => 'cb_id', 'colbits[]' => 'cb_ra', 'colbits[]' => 'cb_mag');`

Comment: Unfortunately the common gateway interface doesn't accept colbits to be an array. I had to add the params manually to the query string.

Comment: Your `$data` array can't possibly work -- an associative array can't have the same key multiple times. If the server accepted the values that way, the proper thing would be `$data = array('colbits' => array('cb_id','cb_ra','cb_mag'));`. But this server doesn't want `colbits[]` parameters.